# javascript subtraction with '- -'

Tags: javascript, subtraction

### question

today I have meet a strange calculate, it was like this:

```
"4"- -19
```

between the '-' is a space and is needed

the answer is 23---a number

how it works?

### someone's suggestion

my colleague say that is equal to:

```
"4"-(0-19)
```

and this is really make me think that "oh this is the truth"

but I don't know how ?

isn't the order of calculate is from left to right?
why '- -' different
and what does this mean?

Comment: -- is equiv to `- * -` which is `+`. I don't know but wouldn't the order of evaluation be implementation dependent?

Comment: You already have many answers explaining the math. I just wanted to point out that the space beetween the two "-" is necessary because otherwise it probably would be interpreted as the "--" operator, which works in the following way: `x-- = x-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urZd3/)

It's quite easy to test.

```
var x = "4" - -19;
```

In this situation `toString()` conversion is applied/

```
var y= "2" + 2;
// y would be a string: "22", not 4.
```

When you use the `-` operator, the default conversion is to `Number()`. `"4"` becomes `4` and you get `4 - (-19)`.

```
4 - (-19) = 4 + 19 = 23;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have focus too much on '- -' but ignore the '-19', it's really my fault

Answer (score 0):

Basic maths really.

```
var x = 4 - (-19);//I included the brackets to demonstrate the effect of the space
//x = 23
```

Notice, that it is interpreted as -19 (negative 19)

Subtracting a negative number has the same effect as adding the positive equivalent of that number. So it would translate to: `4 + 19 = 23`

It is also important to note that your example only produces a number result because the operation is `-`, if addition (`+`) was used, the it would perform a string concatenation instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first minus is as in subtraction and the second minus is as in negative.

So 4 minus negative 19 equals to 23

That's my guess;)